# How to use a bool as an int?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Say I have two buttons on a form.  If the first button gets hidden (visible = false) I would prefer the second button to move over.

In VB I can make a concise assignment:

```
Button2.Left = 22 - (90 * Button1.Visible)
```

But this does not work in C#.  The only way I could figure out makes the code more wordy than VB (I didn't think that was possible) while making it less readable:

```
button2.Left = 22 - (90 * Convert.ToInt32(button1.Visible));
```

That handy shorcut (using a boolean in an assignment to avoid using an if) has existed for decades.  Did Micorsoft kill it in C# or is there a way to still use it without adding function calls or the like?

Comment: Use an appropriate combination of container, autosizing, anchoring and docking to get the correct result. Do not calculate the new position by hand

Comment: As Eric Lippert has pointed out [numerous](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c/) [times](https://ericlippert.com/2007/08/14/c-and-the-pit-of-despair/), C# wasn't designed by taking an existing language and taking bits out.

Comment: Create an extension method on bool called AsInt()

Comment: Don't forget, VB converts TRUE to -1

Comment: @Emo, your solution is impossible.  These buttons are on a user control and the developer can toggle the buttons by using properties.

Comment: @Damien, don't know where that statement came from but to help you become unconfused I will clarify.  Using bools in assignments has been around since the apple II and numerous other languages after along with if, for, ect.  to see it missing in one modern language and present in another is surprising.  You can also do a = 5 + (b < 10) but not in C#.  It can be very valuable in a loop.

Comment: @John - I'm quite familiar with the concept. It was the "Did Micorsoft kill it in C#" phrasing that led to my comment. And just because something has existed for a long time doesn't mean that one shouldn't re-examine their basis. Here, implicitly converting a boolean to an int (and bringing with it the assumption that the boolean has an explicit value, either 1 or -1) may feel "natural" to you, but it may be indicative of a potential bug - i.e. did you *intend* for that conversion, or had you intended to access a different (int) property or apply more logic?

Comment: @John - then change the user control.

Comment: @Emo, change the user control???  That makes even less sense then your prior post.  I am creating a user control.  There is nothing to change to.  If you scroll down you will find a number of solutions that are an order of magnitude easier than any of your suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static int ToInt(this bool Value)
  {
    return Value ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

then use

```
Button2.Left = 22 - (90 * Button1.Visible.ToInt())
```

Comment: That answers the question.  I am using Pedro's answer though, I will keep this idea in mind for the future.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)...

```
button2.Left = button1.Visible ?  22 : -68;
```

Answer (score 2):

It can't be used directly but this might be a suitable shortcut:

```
Button2.Left = 22 - (90 * Button1.Visible ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Much better than my solution, although Pedro's is a little more concise.

Answer (score -1):

you change as fallow,

```
Button2.Left = 22 - (90 * Convert.ToInt16(Button1.Visible))
```

Just Convert Boolean if 1 get is true or 0 get is false

Comment: Which version of C# are you using - I get a compile time error "Cannot cast type 'bool' to type 'int'."

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't work.  Hint: test your solutions first before posting.